# Converting a string in JSON object and validating

Tags: java, json

I am trying to validate this string below. Actually I am receiving this string in my servlet, now I need to validate these values at backend. What is the right way to do so. Shall I first convert it to JSON Object then to HashMap? Please suggest the correct/appropriate approach to be used here. I am quite new to Java and JSON.

String is

```
"{"if_ack":4},{"if_cmd":1,"if_state":1},{"if_cmd":1,"if_state":5}"
```

Comment: String is - "{"if_ack":4},{"if_cmd":1,"if_state":1},{"if_cmd":1,"if_state":5}"

Comment: First you can edit your post, so the String is displayed within the question. Second i guess thats no correct JSON format, because of missing brackets. Therefore nothing can convert this string automatically. Possible solution is to surround it with `[` and `]` so it becomes a `JSONArray` or `{ "root": <insert string> }` like a `JSONObject`

Comment: thanks @ceekay, I am trying as you have suggested!!

Answer (score 0):

I am using GSON for processing JSON at server. For example:

```
InputStream is (send by client, JSON format)
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<YourClass> items = gson.fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<List<YourClass>>()
```

YourClass should have attributes like if_ack, if_state, if_cmd,...

Then you use as simple as this:

```
for (YourClass item : items) {
   //do whatever you want
}
```

EDIT: your string should be in correct JSON format like this (JSON array): [{"if_ack":4}, {"if_cmd":1,"if_state":1}, {"if_cmd":1,"if_state":5}]

EXAMPLE:
You have JSON like this : `[{"id": "1", "image": "test1"}, {"id": "2", "image": "test2"}]`

YourClass.java should be:

```
public class YourClass{
  private int id;
  private String image;
  //+ constructor, getters, setters,...
}
```

On server you can receive JSON from client side by InputStream is:

```
Reader reader =  new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<YourClass> items = gson.fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<List<YourClass>>();
```

and then:

```
for (YourClass item: items){
   //acces to item properties like item.id, item.image
}
```

Comment: Thanks bud, trying it out!!

Comment: hi, i did converted the format to JSONArray as suggested by using [ ]. I am able to access the id for each java object but still not sure how to validatae. Your approach is not very clear. I am a new bee in java and json, it will be great if you explain how you are validating, sorry for minor questions, I am trying to learn :)Thanks!!

Comment: I added an example to my answer. I do not know exactly what you mean by how to validate, I hope you undestand now.